# Ext.ui.iFrame not work

Tags: javascript, extjs

Problem to insert Html code Ext.ui.iFrame 
In EXTJS, i want to insert the html code below in a iframe :

Test

The code ExtJs dosen't work
Ext.create('Ext.ux.IFrame', {
                    id: iframeId,
                    contentEl=x
  }

Comment: did you only need to insert html code inside a panel? or you need an iframe to show an other page inside yours?

Comment: which EXT version are you using?

Comment: I use ExtJs version 6.02

Comment: I need to insert a button for example in iframe ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`setHtml()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.ux.IFrame.html#cfg-html) method for insert html in [`uxiframe`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.ux.IFrame.html).

In this **[FIIDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c0i)**, I have created a demo using `uxiframe`. I hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'TestIframe',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.IFrame'],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'hbox',
            title: 'Ux iFrame example',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'uxiframe',
                itemId: 'uxiframe',
                height: window.innerHeight,
                width: '100%',
                src: 'https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor'
            }],
            tbar: ['->', {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Insert HTML',
                margin: '0 15 0 0',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('panel').down('#uxiframe').setHtml(`<form action="/action_page.php">First name:<br><input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>Last name:<br><input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form> `);
                }
            }]
        });

    }
});
```